# Populating Tabs WinForms Goes Undetected without User View

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs

This might just be a small quirk. But I've built a small windows form application with multiple tabs.

I have a feature that allows users to "load" the entries in each of the tabs by opening a json file. This lets them avoid manually inserting the data. At the same time, I have a "check" to make sure that all required fields have been populated.

What I've found is that even if the load process is successfully populating all the right fields, the user still needs to select each tab (even though they are already filled), in order to avoid hitting the flag.

Hopefully, this makes sense. Right now, my work around is to have the program flip through each tab automatically upon "load", but it seems strange that winforms can't detect a text box has been filled unless the tab is viewed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some events only fire when the control is visible. This sounds like what you should do is decouple the text entries from the control and store them in another object which fires off the filled events then do data binding to those entries.

This has the nice benefit of decoupling the UI from the data storage (always a nice thing) as well as freeing you from the vagaries of the .net UI system (both winforms and wpf have 'interesting' quirks like the above which assume specific behavior preferences).